# how send groupSMS in php

Tags: php, excel

Here i want to do send group SMS ,first user upload one xl file,after that i select that xl file and how many mobile number are there in that xl file i send one OTP for all mobile numbers ,Here this code working only one number that means in that xl file total 1 number is there means it working but more than number is there means it is not working.i think loop is not working perfectly.

---

$phone_number = 9986528665//now working

---

$phone_number = 99865286658553880306960024910099445122469857765222 // more than one not working

```html
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
include 'excel_reader.php';// include the class
include 'sendSMSapi.php';
  $group_id = $_POST['group_id'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_group WHERE id='$group_id'");
    $return=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    //$data[]=$row;
    $groupfile ='upload/'.$row['group_file'];
    } 
   $excel = new PhpExcelReader;
   $excel->read($groupfile);
   
      function sheetData($sheet) {
      $result = ''; 
      $row = 2;
      while($row <= $sheet['numRows']) {
      $cell = isset($sheet['cells'][$row][1]) ? $sheet['cells'][$row][1] : '';
   $result .= $cell;   
      $row++;
     }
     return $result;
    }

     $nr_sheets = count($excel->sheets);// here getting 1
  
     $phone_number = ''; 
 // traverses the number of sheets and sets html table with each sheet data in $excel_data
 for($i=0; $i<$nr_sheets; $i++) { 
 
    echo $phone_number = sheetData($excel->sheets[$i]);//Here i got all phone number like 99861286658553880306960024910099445122469857765222
 
  $sendsms =new sendsms("http://alerts.solutionsuiksean.com/api","A2ba2hgfgh745fcsc5775cef9787e834b3b01c", "ADLMG");
  
  $smsTemp = $message." is your OTP to register with WDI. Please use it and validate your registration.";
  
  $sendsms->send_sms($phone_number, $smsTemp, 'http://www.g2evolution.co.in/', 'PHP'); 
   
 }
 
   
     
    
?>
```

Comment: the domain http://alerts.solutionsuiksean.com does not exist

Comment: That one changed,That OTP code is working fine,$phone_number value getting more than 1 means that time not working